# How can I Add Image of Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image

When I click on image while adding new I didn't get any option to add image or upload image 
[image]

Question is how can i add image for product?

Comment: Check the permission, Check that you have flash plugin enabled. Try on another browser.

Answer (score 0):

check your permissions, sudo chmod -R 777 media

Comment: or sudo chmod -R 775 media better

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission of media directory

`sudo chmod -R 777 media`

Comment: I am new to magento I have only access to admin panel how can i run this command?

Comment: the server is localhost?

Comment: thx smart guy for you advise...